# Really impossible to make package with Theos

Tags: makefile, package, theos, springboard

I really don't manage to "**make package**" with Theos for a Tweak made by me, so I copied the "*unlockchanger*" example on the web (here https://github.com/codyd51/Theos-Examples/tree/master/unlockchanger ) and tried to do "make package". I get these errors:

```
iPhone-di-Gabriele:/var/mobile/unlockchanger root# make package
/var/mobile/unlockchanger/theos/makefiles/targets/Darwin-arm/iphone.mk:43: Targeting iOS 4.0 and higher is not supported with iphone-gcc. Forcing clang.
/var/mobile/unlockchanger/theos/makefiles/targets/Darwin-arm/iphone.mk:53: Deploying to iOS 3.0 while building for 6.0 will generate armv7-only binaries.
Making all for tweak UnlockChanger...
 Preprocessing Tweak.xm...
 Compiling Tweak.xm...
In file included from Tweak.xm:3:
/var/mobile/unlockchanger/theos/include/substrate.h:57:20: error: unknown type name 'pid_t'
bool MSHookProcess(pid_t pid, const char *library);
                   ^
/var/mobile/unlockchanger/theos/include/substrate.h:69:1: error: unknown type name 'IMP'
IMP MSHookMessage(Class _class, SEL sel, IMP imp, const char *prefix _default(NULL));
^
/var/mobile/unlockchanger/theos/include/substrate.h:69:42: error: unknown type name 'IMP'
IMP MSHookMessage(Class _class, SEL sel, IMP imp, const char *prefix _default(NULL));
                                         ^
/var/mobile/unlockchanger/theos/include/substrate.h:69:79: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NULL'
IMP MSHookMessage(Class _class, SEL sel, IMP imp, const char *prefix _default(NULL));
                                                                              ^
/var/mobile/unlockchanger/theos/include/substrate.h:48:27: note: expanded from macro '_default'
#define _default(value) = value
                          ^
/var/mobile/unlockchanger/theos/include/substrate.h:71:45: error: unknown type name 'IMP'
void MSHookMessageEx(Class _class, SEL sel, IMP imp, IMP *result);
                                            ^
/var/mobile/unlockchanger/theos/include/substrate.h:71:54: error: unknown type name 'IMP'
void MSHookMessageEx(Class _class, SEL sel, IMP imp, IMP *result);
                                                     ^
/var/mobile/unlockchanger/theos/include/substrate.h:125:92: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NULL'
static inline Type_ *MSHookMessage(Class _class, SEL sel, Type_ *imp, const char *prefix = NULL) {
                                                                                           ^
/var/mobile/unlockchanger/theos/include/substrate.h:126:82: error: unknown type name 'IMP'
    return reinterpret_cast<Type_ *>(MSHookMessage(_class, sel, reinterpret_cast<IMP>(imp), prefix));
                                                                                 ^
/var/mobile/unlockchanger/theos/include/substrate.h:132:58: error: unknown type name 'IMP'
    return MSHookMessageEx(_class, sel, reinterpret_cast<IMP>(imp), reinterpret_cast<IMP *>(result));
                                                         ^
/var/mobile/unlockchanger/theos/include/substrate.h:132:86: error: unknown type name 'IMP'
    return MSHookMessageEx(_class, sel, reinterpret_cast<IMP>(imp), reinterpret_cast<IMP *>(result));
                                                                                     ^
/var/mobile/unlockchanger/theos/include/substrate.h:137:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Ivar'
    Ivar ivar(class_getInstanceVariable(object_getClass(self), name));
    ^
/var/mobile/unlockchanger/theos/include/substrate.h:138:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ivar'
    void *pointer(ivar == NULL ? NULL : reinterpret_cast<char *>(self) + ivar_getOffset(ivar));
                  ^
/var/mobile/unlockchanger/theos/include/substrate.h:138:27: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NULL'
    void *pointer(ivar == NULL ? NULL : reinterpret_cast<char *>(self) + ivar_getOffset(ivar));
                          ^
/var/mobile/unlockchanger/theos/include/substrate.h:138:34: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NULL'
    void *pointer(ivar == NULL ? NULL : reinterpret_cast<char *>(self) + ivar_getOffset(ivar));
                                 ^
/var/mobile/unlockchanger/theos/include/substrate.h:138:89: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ivar'
    void *pointer(ivar == NULL ? NULL : reinterpret_cast<char *>(self) + ivar_getOffset(ivar));
                                                                                        ^
/var/mobile/unlockchanger/theos/include/substrate.h:294:71: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NULL'
    return MSHookFunction(symbol, replace, reinterpret_cast<Type_ **>(NULL));
                                                                      ^
/var/mobile/unlockchanger/theos/include/substrate.h:298:85: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NULL'
static inline void MSHookSymbol(Type_ *&value, const char *name, MSImageRef image = NULL) {
                                                                                    ^
/var/mobile/unlockchanger/theos/include/substrate.h:303:86: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NULL'
static inline void MSHookFunction(const char *name, Type_ *replace, Type_ **result = NULL) {
                                                                                     ^
/var/mobile/unlockchanger/theos/include/substrate.h:310:104: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NULL'
static inline void MSHookFunction(MSImageRef image, const char *name, Type_ *replace, Type_ **result = NULL) {
                                                                                                       ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [obj/Tweak.xm.7838be1a.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [UnlockChanger.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

Some detail:

- I'm on iOS8.1, with an iPhone 5. Everything installed from Cydia
- ..and on Windows 8.1 with WinSCP and PuTTY
- I've installed *Theos*, *Perl*.. everything (Also "*BigBoss recommended packages*")
- I had to install also **LLVM+Clang** because *make* didn't find a "*clang++*" command
- I've tried to dump classes, instead of taking them from the web
- I've updated *substrate.h* in /include/ and *libsubstrate.dylib* in /lib/

If I try to "make package" on my tweak for SpringBoard, where in Tweak.xm I do:

```
#import <SpringBoard/Springboard.h>
```

I get these errors:

```
iPhone-di-Gabriele:/var/mobile/mytweak root# make package
/var/mobile/mytweak/theos/makefiles/targets/Darwin-arm/iphone.mk:43: Targeting iOS 4.0 and higher is not supported with iphone-gcc. Forcing clang.
/var/mobile/mytweak/theos/makefiles/targets/Darwin-arm/iphone.mk:53: Deploying to iOS 3.0 while building for 6.0 will generate armv7-only binaries.
Making all for tweak mytweak...
 Preprocessing Tweak.xm...
 Compiling Tweak.xm...
In file included from Tweak.xm:1:
/var/mobile/mytweak/theos/include/SpringBoard.h:33:19: error: field has incomplete type 'struct CGSize'
    struct CGSize size;
                  ^
/var/mobile/mytweak/theos/include/SpringBoard.h:33:12: note: forward declaration of 'CGSize'
    struct CGSize size;
           ^
/var/mobile/mytweak/theos/include/SpringBoard.h:229:34: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSObject'
@protocol APSConnectionDelegate <NSObject>
                                 ^
/var/mobile/mytweak/theos/include/SpringBoard.h:233:37: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSObject'
@protocol AVExternalDeviceDelegate <NSObject>
                                    ^
/var/mobile/mytweak/theos/include/SpringBoard.h:236:27: error: cannot find protocol declaration for
      'BBSectionIdentity'
@protocol BBDataProvider <BBSectionIdentity>
                          ^
/var/mobile/mytweak/theos/include/SpringBoard.h:240:31: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSObject'
@protocol BBObserverDelegate <NSObject>
                              ^
/var/mobile/mytweak/theos/include/SpringBoard.h:246:30: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSObject'
@protocol BBSectionIdentity <NSObject>
                             ^
/var/mobile/mytweak/theos/include/SpringBoard.h:250:41: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSObject'
@protocol BSSettingDescriptionProvider <NSObject>
                                        ^
/var/mobile/mytweak/theos/include/SpringBoard.h:255:34: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSObject'
@protocol BSTransactionObserver <NSObject>
                                 ^
/var/mobile/mytweak/theos/include/SpringBoard.h:258:31: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSObject'
@protocol BSWatchdogDelegate <NSObject>
                              ^
/var/mobile/mytweak/theos/include/SpringBoard.h:261:38: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSObject'
@protocol CLLocationManagerDelegate <NSObject>
                                     ^
/var/mobile/mytweak/theos/include/SpringBoard.h:264:41: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSObject'
@protocol FBApplicationLibraryObserver <NSObject>
                                        ^
/var/mobile/mytweak/theos/include/SpringBoard.h:267:45: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSObject'
@protocol FBApplicationPlaceholderObserver <NSObject>
                                            ^
/var/mobile/mytweak/theos/include/SpringBoard.h:270:41: error: cannot find protocol declaration for
      'FBProcessObserver'
@protocol FBApplicationProcessObserver <FBProcessObserver>
                                        ^
/var/mobile/mytweak/theos/include/SpringBoard.h:276:37: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSObject'
@protocol FBDisplayManagerObserver <NSObject>
                                    ^
/var/mobile/mytweak/theos/include/SpringBoard.h:279:37: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSObject'
@protocol FBProcessManagerObserver <NSObject>
                                    ^
/var/mobile/mytweak/theos/include/SpringBoard.h:284:30: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSObject'
@protocol FBProcessObserver <NSObject>
                             ^
/var/mobile/mytweak/theos/include/SpringBoard.h:287:35: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSObject'
@protocol FBSceneManagerDelegate <NSObject>
                                  ^
/var/mobile/mytweak/theos/include/SpringBoard.h:293:35: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSObject'
@protocol FBSceneManagerObserver <NSObject>
                                  ^
/var/mobile/mytweak/theos/include/SpringBoard.h:302:46: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSObject'
@protocol FBSynchronizedTransactionDelegate <NSObject>
                                             ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [obj/Tweak.xm.0ad6af3a.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [mytweak.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

I really don't know where is the mistake, I really tried everything, also "make -i" but it doesn't create the dylib file!

Also using my **dumped headers**, for SpringBoard, I get:

```
iPhone-di-Gabriele:/var/mobile/test root# make package
/var/mobile/test/theos/makefiles/targets/Darwin-arm/iphone.mk:43: Targeting iOS 4.0 and higher is not supported with iphone-gcc. Forcing clang.
/var/mobile/test/theos/makefiles/targets/Darwin-arm/iphone.mk:53: Deploying to iOS 3.0 while building for 6.0 will generate armv7-only binaries.
Making all for tweak test...
 Preprocessing Tweak.xm...
 Compiling Tweak.xm...
In file included from Tweak.xm:1:
In file included from /var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:9:
In file included from /var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/SBBannerContainerViewController.h:8:
In file included from /var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning.h:8:
In file included from /var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/NSObject.h:8:
/var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard-Structs.h:26:2: error:
      unknown type name 'BOOL'
        BOOL _field1;
        ^
/var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard-Structs.h:27:2: error:
      unknown type name 'BOOL'
        BOOL _field2;
        ^
/var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard-Structs.h:28:2: error:
      unknown type name 'BOOL'
        BOOL _field3;
        ^
/var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard-Structs.h:29:2: error:
      unknown type name 'BOOL'
        BOOL _field4;
        ^
/var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard-Structs.h:30:2: error:
      unknown type name 'BOOL'
        BOOL _field5;
        ^
/var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard-Structs.h:66:2: error:
      unknown type name 'BOOL'
        BOOL itemIsEnabled[25];
        ^
/var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard-Structs.h:67:2: error:
      unknown type name 'BOOL'
        BOOL timeString[64];
        ^
/var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard-Structs.h:70:2: error:
      unknown type name 'BOOL'
        BOOL serviceString[100];
        ^
/var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard-Structs.h:71:2: error:
      unknown type name 'BOOL'
        BOOL serviceCrossfadeString[100];
        ^
/var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard-Structs.h:72:2: error:
      unknown type name 'BOOL'
        BOOL serviceImages[2][100];
        ^
/var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard-Structs.h:73:2: error:
      unknown type name 'BOOL'
        BOOL operatorDirectory[1024];
        ^
/var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard-Structs.h:80:2: error:
      unknown type name 'BOOL'
        BOOL batteryDetailString[150];
        ^
/var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard-Structs.h:86:2: error:
      unknown type name 'BOOL'
        BOOL activityDisplayId[256];
        ^
/var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard-Structs.h:102:2: error:
      unknown type name 'BOOL'
        BOOL _field3[4088];
        ^
/var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard-Structs.h:116:2: error:
      unknown type name 'BOOL'
        BOOL __opaque[40];
        ^
/var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard-Structs.h:162:2: error:
      unknown type name 'BOOL'
        BOOL valid;
        ^
/var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard-Structs.h:179:2: error:
      unknown type name 'BOOL'
        BOOL isValid;
        ^
In file included from Tweak.xm:1:
In file included from /var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:9:
In file included from /var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/SBBannerContainerViewController.h:8:
In file included from /var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning.h:8:
/var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/NSObject.h:10:1: error: redefinition
      of 'NSString' as different kind of symbol
@class NSString;
^
/var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard-Structs.h:135:3: note:
      previous definition is here
} NSString;
  ^
In file included from Tweak.xm:1:
In file included from /var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:9:
In file included from /var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/SBBannerContainerViewController.h:8:
In file included from /var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning.h:8:
/var/mobile/test/theos/include/SpringBoard/NSObject.h:24:3: error: expected a
      type
-(BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)selector;
  ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [obj/Tweak.xm.56f06e0e.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [test.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

Thank you to everyone who wants to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get these errors, make sure you **have not extracted, or copied SDK folder** (*iPhoneOSX.X.sdk*) on **Windows**, because in this way you will **lose every (symbolic) link** between sdk's files. So manage and organize your sdk folder on Mac OS, iOS or Linux (but I didn't tried on this one).

Good Luck!